# Mac localhost is not available after upgrade to OSX El Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

From `httpd -v`, I get the below:

```
 Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
 Server built:   Aug 22 2015 16:51:57
```

Also, `etc/hosts` is as follows:

```
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost 
    fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

I start the server using `sudo apachectl start` and it returns no error. However, I am not able to connect to `localhost` on a web browser. Would you suggest a solution? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked your `/etc/hosts` - does it cost IPV6 record for localhost?
I had the same issue - and adding `::1             localhost` helped. Let me know.

Comment: Please see the update..

Comment: when you `ping localhost` you get `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: yes, I get `PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms`

Comment: All right. Lets try: 
`curl -v http://localhost/`
and then check `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` - is there something interesting? "Not loading" - there must be an error which describes what is it. Could it be httpd.conf not allowing enough permissions?

Comment: curl -v http://localhost/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying fe80::1...
* connect to fe80::1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: tail /var/log/apache2/error_log
tail: /var/log/apache2/error_log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if https://donatstudios.com/PHP-in-OS-X-Yosemite helps you re-configure the httpd.conf

Comment: I get the below error from `apachectl configtest`: `httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found`

Comment: Comment out the offending lines and keep running apachectl configtest until satisfied. I have enabled `mod_authn_file.so, mod_authn_core.so, mod_authz_host.so, mod_authz_groupfile.so, mod_authz_core.so` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need IPv6 there is an easy fix for this.

I was all of a sudden unable to access localhost:631 (CUPS).
I Changed IPv6 to link-local.

Problem solved.